# Maintain scroll position when going back and using query params

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm working on an application that has a listing of events and each event has its own detailed show page. Everything seems fine, but one complaint I've received is that we're not maintaining the scroll position when going from the detail page back to the index listing.

For an example of the ideal behavior, go to http://discuss.emberjs.com/, scroll down the page a ways, click a link, then click the back button. You're brought to same place you were previously at, somewhere further down the page.

With our app, if you try to do this, you're brought back to the top of the page while the results are reloaded from the API. Then when the results load, your position is lost.

Is there a way to achieve what Discourse does while using query params?